# Question| Creating a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am familiar with jQuery and I wanted to ask something correlating to a plugin/code that I am trying to create.

1) What kinds of plugins that I can create, except for the : $('element').myPlugin(); ?
Can I create a plugin that creates a div? like so: myPlugin();
By using jQuery standards?

2) Let's say that I want to create a nice sticky div with jQuery and I want it to be the easiest for the user to implement, how can I do so?
(e.g. The user will only need to paste the function somewhere in the code after the DOM was ready).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The basis of creating a plugin for jQuery is actually quite simple.

Following the jQuery plugin authoring guidelines is a good idea. Bear in mind that

1) plugins files should be named jquery.PLUGINNAME.js and

2) always attach your plugins to `jQuery` instead of `$`, so aliases can be easily set using the `noConflict()` method.

The structure required to extend the jQuery.fn object is

```
jQuery.fn.myFirstPlugin = function () {
   return this.each (function () {
     //Write your logic here

   });
}
```

This is how you will call it

```
$('#test').firstPlugin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link of the simple tutorial on how to make a jquery plugin:

http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html

Comment: This is not the solution that I am looking for, I know how to make the standard jQuery plugin...
But my problem is that I want to have a "plugin" that creates by it self all of the divs...
How should I do that?